# How can I fix signed apk /app bundle signing issue - Android Studio Exception failed for task app: validate signing release

Tags: android, flutter

I've tried recreating the key and changing the password but I haven't been able to fix this issue - I receive either keystore file not found or can’t read keystore file that is store in the android folder. I'm posting the code and screenshot of file structure in the hope that someone will see something that I'm overlooking. Thanks for your help.

keystore.properties

```
storePassword=storePassword
keyPassword=keyPassword
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=android/keystore.jks

error msg:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
Keystore file '/Users/user/Documents/dev/nistnotesapp/android/app/android/keystore.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.
```

---

```
storePassword=storePassword
keyPassword=keyPassword
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=..\/keystore.jks

error msg:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key upload from store
"/Users/user/Documents/dev/nistnotesapp/android/keystore.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or
password was incorrect
```

build.gradle

```
signingConfigs {
release {
    keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
    keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
    storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
    storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
}}
```

I also tried ./gradlew clean; invalidate cache and restart; flutter build apk; deleting build/app/outputs
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved:

<kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Flutter</kbd> > <kbd>Open for editing</kbd> in Android Studio

<kbd>Build</kbd> > <kbd>Generate Signed APK/App Bundle</kbd> appeared, and I was able to generate the key.